# Non-blocking recv on an async channel?

Tags: asynchronous, websocket, rust, channel

1. I was looking for an equivalent of `try_recv()` in `futures::channel::mpsc::Receiver` and couldn't find one. Is there one? There is `try_next()` but I don't think it does what I want. I certainly don't want it to panic if I call it multiple times on an empty channel.
2. Alternatively, is it ok to use `std::sync::mpsc::channel` in async code, as long as I never do a blocking read on the channel (i.e. always use `try_recv()`) ? What about sending to it from an async function and consuming it in a sync thread?

Here's a little more detail on what I'm trying to do:

I'm building a game where players connect to the server via websocket. The websocket side will be async, and each connection will spawn a task to loop over incoming messages and put them into a channel. That channel is the thing I need advice on - whether it should use `futures::channel::mpsc::channel` (and make the game loop async - but see question 1) or `std::sync::mpsc::channel` (see question 2).

The game engine will run in a separate thread, and will check for player inputs on that channel (each player has its own channel) once per frame. I want to avoid the possibility that a bad (or slow) websocket client could flood the connection and slow down the main game engine, so I want to only process one incoming message per frame for each player channel. If a player's own channel fills up, they only hurt themselves. But the check for one incoming message per frame needs to be non-blocking because it's running inside a game loop.

So as per question 2 above, will the following work?

Async websocket -> sync channel -> sync game loop (and the same in reverse)

Comment: `futures::channel::mpsc::Receiver` IS a [`stream/futures`](https://docs.rs/futures/0.3.4/futures/channel/mpsc/struct.Receiver.html#impl-Stream)... so just do `rx.await :p`

Comment: I wondered if I could do this. Is there any good tutorial/examples/documentation on this? I'll do some experimenting. Thanks!

Comment: not much https://rust-lang.github.io/async-book/01_getting_started/01_chapter.html

Comment: When I try to do `rx.await` I'm getting `the trait bound futures_channel::mpsc::Receiver<PlayerMessageExternal>: core::future::future::Future is not satisfied`. This is confusing. Is it saying `futures::channel::mpsc::Receiver` doesn't impl `Future` ? Or is it a mismatch between futures v0.3 and the core lib ?

Comment: I advice you to use tokio https://docs.rs/tokio/0.2.13/tokio/sync/mpsc/fn.channel.html

Answer (score 2):

Looks like `try_recv()` is not yet implemented for async-std, though it appears to be not far away (currently in review).
https://github.com/async-rs/async-std/issues/579

As mentioned by @Stargateur (see comments under original question), tokio's mpsc implementation supports `try_recv()`.

I've switched my code over to using tokio 0.2 (and tokio_tungstenite for websockets) and it is working great.